# Combine linear-gradient with dynamic background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to achieve color overlay on background images [as demonstrated at w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_hero_image), but I want to do it for a dynamically set background-image (I'm currently working with VueJS).

### What I try to achieve:

```html
<div class="hero-image">...</div>
```

```css
.hero-image {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('image.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

### First attempt - extract *background-image* to html:

**Problem:** This will override the color information and only use the *background-image* settings. I also tried with *background* attribute instead of *background-color* in the css code.

```html
<div class="hero-image" :style="{ backgroundImage: `url('${image}')`}">...</div>
```

```css
.hero-image {
    background-color: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
    background-size: cover;
}
```

### Second attempt - extract the complete *background* attribute:

**Problem:** This works except the *background-size* attribute is now ignored. I tried to add *cover* to the *background*-attribute in the html but it does not work either.

```html
<div class="hero-image" :style="{ 
  background: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('${image}')`
}">...</div>
```

```css
.hero-image {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: in the second attempt replace `background` by `background-image` and you can use `background-size`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use background image and color together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903659/why-cant-i-use-background-image-and-color-together)

Comment: you can also try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54652984/8620333 (make the image a CSS variable)

Comment: Wow thanks @TemaniAfif, your first answer did the trick! Didn't know it was that easy..

Comment: instead of background in your inline style - use background-image otherwise the shorthand inline property will override the background size in your style sheet

Comment: I need to use inline to dynamically set the background image @Pete

Comment: That's what I'm saying - if you use background - it is shorthand for all background properties and therefore the inline style takes precedence over anything that is not marked !important in your stylesheet - that's why your background size is ignored in your second attempt.  By only targeting the image (as that's the only dynamic thing) your stylesheet will not be overridden

Comment: Oh, you're right! I read that incorrectly, but that was exactly what had already been mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Temani, the second attempt should use *background-image* in the html instead of just *background*. Solution:

```html
<div class="hero-image" :style="{ 
  backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('${image}')`
}">...</div>
```

```css
.hero-image {
    background-size: cover;
}
```